# SQL: strange query performance behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have two tables:

- `Nodes` - really small table, about 20 rows
- `Events` - quite big table, about 10M rows

and following query:

```
select 
    e.DeviceAlias as Mac, n.NodeId, n.city as City, n.street as Street, e.Status,
    CASE WHEN e.Status = 'U' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE 'Known' END as 'Source', 
    COUNT (*) as 'Count', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.SentMessageId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SentMsgCount
from 
    events e
join 
    Nodes n on e.NodeId = n.NodeId
where
    e.InsertDate >= @startdate
    and e.InsertDate <= @enddate
group by 
    e.DeviceAlias, e.Status, n.NodeId, n.city, n.street
```

The query executes for over 5 minutes. I have all the required indexes applied, and sql perf advisor suggests no additional indexes or statistics. However if I get rid of the join and execute following query:

```
select 
    e.DeviceAlias as Alias, NodeId,
    CASE WHEN e.Status = 'U' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE 'Known' END as 'Source', 
    COUNT (*) as 'Count', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.SentMessageId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SentMsgCount
from 
    events e
where
    e.InsertDate >= '2014-07-01'
    and e.InsertDate <= '2014-11-28'
group by 
    e.DeviceAlias,nodeid, e.Status
```

it executes in 30 seconds.

The simple solution is to use second query and fill the rest of the data from Nodes table in c# code.

But that bothers me is why the join with so small table is giving this huge performance overhead? Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure it really takes 5 minutes to execute, or 5 minutes to return the whole output of the query to the client? Can you try wrapping the query in something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) T and see if it still executes for 5 minutes?

Comment: do you have up-to-date statistics?

Comment: I'm executing both queries from management studio. As far as I know it displays time of executing the query AND returning the output. Anyway, the second query executes in 30s while amount of data is almost the same (exactly the same number of rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erikkallen, you are my man ;)
Updating statistics reduced execution time to 38s!
Anyway - WTF?? I had auto update statistics set to true on this database... The Events table grows very fast, so the autoupdate should be taking place every few hours according to "Table has over 500 rows and there is an increase of 500 + 20% of the table size since the last update" rule (from http://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-server-statistics-maintenance-and-best-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the explain plan: SQL Server (if my memory serves me correctly) can use either Nested Loop, Hash or Merge algorithms: if Nested Loop turns up on the plan (which I doubt), then the database will look in - i.e. loop through - the small table for each of the million or so rows in the larger table, one loop for each "parent" row. If merge is used, then there needs to be less looping, but the datasets will most probably have to be pre-sorted. For Hash joins, the external set can "look up" the matching row from a hash table.

Either way the overhead is not unexpected for such a large disparity in set sizes: you might like to also try an inline subquery, normally best avoided but with such size disparities the results may be suprising.